# Typescript recursive method call to Omit property and method

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have specification like this

```
type SpecificType<U, T extends keyof U> = {
    Name: T,
    Value: U[T]
}

class Builder<TItems> {
    private items: SpecificType<TItems, any>[] = [];

    and<TType extends keyof TItems>(type: TType, value: TItems[TType]): Builder<Omit<TItems, TType>> {
        return this.append(this.create(type, value));
    }

    append<TType extends keyof TItems>(item: SpecificType<TItems, TType>): Builder<Omit<TItems, TType>> {
        this.items.push(item);
        return this as Builder<Omit<TItems, TType>>;
    }

    build(): SpecificType<any, any>[] {
        return this.items;
    }

    private create<TType extends keyof TItems>(type: TType, value: TItems[TType]): SpecificType<TItems, TType> {
        return {
            Name: type,
            Value: value
        }
    }
}
```

Builder is building items based upon generic type, which is basically map between name and type like so:

```
type Types = {
    "Type1": undefined,
    "Type2": { MaxAge: number }
}
```

And here is how I use builder

```
const itemBuilder = new Builder<Types>();
itemBuilder
    .and("Type1", undefined)
    .and("Type2", { MaxAge: 3 });
```

I have 2 questions

1. I'm omitting specific type mapping with each call to `and` or `append` because those methods can be called only once per specific `key` in `TItems` (or in this case `Types`). Is it possible to also remove `and` and `append` when all `TItems` keys have been used? Currently if I call another `and` on `itemBuilder` autocomplete will offer this: `and(type: never, value: never)`. It would be much better if there was no `and` and `append` in autocomplete for `itemBuilder` after those first 2 calls.
2. If you look at first `and` call on `itemBuilder`, since `Type1` mapping is `undefined`, I have to pass `undefined` as value. Is it possible to somehow pass just name to `and` method if it doesn't have mapping - because resulting `SpecificType` is just `{ Name: string }` and I don't need `value` (or I could declare mapping somehow different without using `undefined` maybe??)

Comment: Do you really want `build()` to return `SpecificType<any, any>[]` instead of the actual type of the built thing?  If so, fine, the question as asked can probably be answered.  Otherwise I'd rather answer the question so that `Builder` keeps track both of `T` and the list of properties it's already built.

Comment: That's what I was thinking of having but for now I don't have any use of it, so I don't need typed build method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'm switching to the naming convention where type parameters are one or two capital letters, where `T` and `U` signify general types and `K` and `P` for key types.  That's more standard for TypeScript, for whatever reason.

Here's how I'd do it.  For question 1, I'll create the `NextBuilder` type alias, which looks like this:

```
type NextBuilder<T, K extends keyof T> = keyof T extends K
  ? Omit<Builder<{}>, "and" | "append">
  : Builder<Omit<T, K>>;
```

It's a [conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) which checks if `keyof T` is equal to (or narrower than) `K`.  If so, that means `Omit<T, K>` will be `{}` and there's the case we're trying to deal with.  In such cases, we'll return `Omit<Builder<{}>, "and" | "append">`, which hides the `and()` and `append()` methods as you want.  Otherwise, `Omit<T, K>` will still have some known properties and we'll return `Builder<Omit<T, K>>` as your original code did. Then we change `add()` and `append()` to return `NextBuilder<T, K>` (and use some judicious type assertions to appease the compiler which cannot generally verify assignability to unresolved conditional types), and we're done.  For example, here's the new `append()`:

```
  append<K extends keyof T>(item: SpecificType<T, K>): NextBuilder<T, K> {
    this.items.push(item);
    return this as any;
  }
```

For question 2, I would change the signature of `and()` so that the second parameter is optional in the cases where `undefined` is a possible value of the property.  (So it should also allow you to leave off `value` if you have `type Types = {Type3?: string}`.  The change is a little weird, and I had to jump through a few hoops to make it behave nicely at the call site.  Here's the new `and()`:

```
  and<K extends keyof T>(
    type: K,
    ...[value]: undefined extends T[K]
      ? Parameters<(value?: T[K]) => void>
      : Parameters<(value: T[K]) => void>
  ): NextBuilder<T, K> {
    return this.append(this.create(type, value!)) as any;
  }
```

Okay, so that first parameter is just `type: K`.  Let's go through the second one.  It starts with `...[value]`, meaning that we are using a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) array and immediately [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) it into `value`.  After that comes the rest parameter's type annotation, `:`.  The type of the rest parameter array is a conditional type, whose condition is `undefined extends T[K] ?`.  If `undefined extends T[K]` is true, then the return type is `Parameters<(value?: T[K]) => void>`, which uses the [`Parameters`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.6.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1476-L1479) utility type to get an [optional one-tuple](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) of type `[T[K]?]`. Otherwise the return type is `Parameters<(value: T[K]) => void>`, which is of type `[T[K]]`.  Frankly that's a lot more complex than just `undefined extends T[K] ? [T[K]?] : [T[K]]`, but it has an advantage over the former in that it gives the argument the name `value` in the IntelliSense, and not just something made up like `arg0` (there is a bit of [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#generic-rest-parameters) that mentions if you infer parameters from a function type into a tuple and then put it back into function parameters, the original parameter names are preserved).

Do note that in the implementation I had to use the [non-null assertion operator (`!`)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator) on `value` since the compiler can't verify that `T[K] | undefined` is an acceptable second parameter for `this.create()`.  The non-null assertion is a short way of saying that `value` is actually `T[K]` (which we know it is, since it's only `undefined` if `undefined extends T[K]` is true).

Whew!   So, that's it.

---

Let's stand back and see how it works:

```
const i1 = itemBuilder.and("Type1"); // IntelliSense shows:
// (method) Builder<Types>.and<"Type1">(
//   type: "Type1", value?: undefined
// ): Builder<Pick<Types, "Type2">>
const i2 = i1.and("Type2", { MaxAge: 3 }); // IntelliSense shows:
// (method) Builder<Pick<Types, "Type2">>.and<"Type2">(
//   type: "Type2", value: { MaxAge: number; }
// ): Pick<Builder<{}>, "build">
const i3 = i2.build(); // IntelliSense shows:
// (method) build(): SpecificType<any, any>[]
```

This looks good to me.  When you first use `and()`, you're prompted to enter either `"Type1"` or `"Type2"` as the first parameter.  Once you choose `"Type1"`, the IntelliSense shows that `value` is an optional second parameter and you can leave it out.  The next `and()` only allows you to choose `"Type2"`, and `value` is a required second parameter.  Finally, after this, you are only allowed to call `build()`, as `add()` and `append()` are missing.

That gives you what you wanted, I think.

---

Okay, hope that helps. Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//?ts=Nightly#code/C4TwDgpgBAypDGBLAZo+AVcEA86A0UA0lBAB7AQB2AJgM5QDWEIA9slOgHxQC8UA3gFgAUFCgA5AIYBbCAC4iAbhFiAapIA2AV3kcA2oQC6y4QF8TI0JAllgAIS2IN1CACdcBYrap1GzNhzcfEys7Ogk5D70hCpQAPxQAPLSiMDYDk4u7vymnAQARJI0+VAAPlCFYJDFnLEKGc5u2MmpHkScnBbC8BqStPQNWbjcQqJQYK6IAG6SFFCpENK0CnAQSKgYWG1FIJx6hrxQ+11iRdTYXpE09CEBXAAUsWJWuoR4T1AAdN96M9oQhgUWhoEFQlAg1AiFGu+iMHzECQACpJXDIIBRXLRsPc-jo4gp0AZDABKXjcKYsRDUWpjMRiBTI1GyDFYnGaHQEomknjkynU2LEhTiWyDJr4doCD6udFaVyUKDAAAWiFon0kVR89yVKs+8GlswgWqwBFxEAAhMTSX0oDsTGJTCJYurqudLtDfLcwpx7gtpCsECg0JhIG1CJxBTZyKL3OKw5LaQrlarfaqwFpaIqfRRpMS7XTpcBZfLtfRrbbYg7hLEAEaOZz3COrdZBrY7Ag7PYHUZ0qAFouJnUpvOV2ITaYGqB6iAG3DB6DeGGewKPBMvAlz94J02c9BzwwC-1rQObEPi3dYEZSmVy+M9sRSWQKF6bu9QdT-BSmj7mCsiEfCF4OCweg+G7IDIAARiBEEwQhPM5wAJgUfgoAAWUkUgAEEAHNdEoLRpGrNwoB-MwungFhKFoYB5mzaNDnBAB3KBo1wYDvVzR1hAAegAKl4jgAFEYHQABJcQAHEoHE9BBIAGTk0SYEE8RlKgfjuK4iiqJoxAIMOX1ozVGh7nyOcIPyXMoG47jpMoCgNA0RAYCoWhoAzFhGOWEQbKge5mUVFhqFJVi51oThjPOMysAs70fNs54sAUaLIPyE12QgfEoGBFxYOoeKoAjVjETQBg2MgWgCkQ-IOhEbTqPmBCDIgyLTOqggUPQrDcIUABmEirN80T7IgRznNc9zAq8uQCv89FAuCli6yGEr4DKsKqqwBCaois5sBSiBtriniEoVJKKnaqBtwENCMJwvCCKI1xFBIgqI1WsrWJyPIKlrTIarqyiGsQfq+EQBDPj++tBts4aHKclyqMmzzvJOvyAqC0koeoBtD2bE8cDbG1KF2fYRCAA)

Comment: You really know a lot about typescript (already helped with few questions) :D. Thanks a lot!